# Reconciling compiled prepared statement with execs thereafter in a SQL Server profiling session

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, grails, profiling, grails-orm

We are using SQL Server and GORM (Grails / Hibernate).

Recently our DBA asked me if we could use stored procedures instead of normal Hibernate prepared statements on a certain critical path table in our database. He is not concerned about performance or anything like that, rather he explained that it is very difficult for him to profile Hibernate prepared statements because, loosely quoted, "Somewhere in the session you get a prepared statement that has the SQL text...thereafter you just get execs of the prepared statement. Reconciling the two in a production system is near impossible".

Of course I would prefer to use domain classes with normal insert / update /delete behavior in our application rather than manually building / executing prepared statements. So two questions come to my mind:

1. Can SQL Server Profiler be configured in some way, or is there some technique, to make it easier to profile Hibernate prepared statements? If not...
2. Is there some non-intrusive customization I can do in my Hibernate / Grails app to use the domain classes as I normally would but change the backend code generation (I don't know, perhaps using Hibernate Intercepts... perhaps I can specify an SP to use instead of prepared statements for specific insert / update / delete operations... or perhaps I can indicate that the prepared statement should have a fixed "name" that might help make it identifiable to the DBA in a profiling session...).

**Update**

Example grabbed from SQL Server Profiler session:

```
--sp_prepare on first execute
declare @p1 int
set @p1=8
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P0 int',N'select <columns> from <table> where <primary key> = @P0 ',1
select @p1
go

--sp_execute thereafter
exec sp_execute 8,1
go
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant SQL snippets from SQL Profiler?  Do they use the `sp_prepare` / `sp_execute` family?

Comment: Looks like `sp_prepare` / `sp_execute` family. Updated with snippets.

Answer (score 2):

If it's [`sp_prepare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx), there's an [article on SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/sp_prepexec/76511/) that says you can turn that off in the Hibernate configuration like:

```
<property name='prepare_sql'>false</property>
```

It looks like Hibernate will send parameterized queries with this setting turned off.  Which would allow SQL Server to cache the plan exactly like a prepared query.

However, some articles suggest that without `prepare_sql`, Hibernate will vary the [parameter size for strings](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/tuning-queries-with-ms-sqlserver.aspx).  That would make SQL Server's plan caching useless.  You might want to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It looks like the articles you cite are specifically for NHibernate (which does diverge in some places from Hibernate). However, there does appear to be an analog in the Hibernate world: looks we can set `prepareSQL=2` on our jTDS JDBC driver connection string to generate `sp_executesql` instead of `sp_prepare` / `sp_execute` (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html). But the former is considered only "fast" while the latter "faster"... do you see there really being notable performance differences between these two methods?

Comment: Oh, one more thing: my initial testing indicates that Hibernate w/ prepareSQL=2 in the jTDS connection string does not have the parameter size issue for strings that NHibernate has (it always uses varchar / nvarchar with size corresponding to the column used in the comparison).